# commandLink não cria link na tela

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Estou começando com sf e estou tendo um problema com este projeto.

O comando a seguir não cria o link na tela que eu preciso para ir para a próxima página, só me dá "Novo usuário" escrito na tela:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Financeiro</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Financeiro</h1>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink action="#{usuarioBean.novo}">Novo Usuário</h:commandLink>    
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

Também tentei essa variação, sem sucesso:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{usuarioBean.novo}" value="Novo usuário"/>
```

O método chamado pelo `#{usuarioBean.novo}`

```
public class UsuarioBean {
    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    private String confirmarSenha;

    public String novo() { 
        this.usuario = new Usuario();
        this.usuario.setAtivo(true);
        return "/publico/usuario"; 
    }
}
```

Alguém consegue identificar onde está o erro?

Answer (score 0):

Então, o que eu vi faltando foi o redirect

```
public class UsuarioBean {
private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
private String confirmarSenha;

    public String novo() { 
        this.usuario = new Usuario();
        this.usuario.setAtivo(true);
        return "/publico/usuario.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ainda não deu :/

Comment: Você sabe uma forma de eu chamar o método `#{usuarioBean.novo}` através desse comando: `<a href="publico/usuario.jsf" >Novo Usuário</a>`

Dessa forma está criando o link, mas sem método nenhum.